# error while installing Symfony , Declaration DependencyInjection PSR php, what to do?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, declaration

**Use:**
symfony new my_project_nasdame --version=lts

[OR]

composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name

[OR]

symfony new test_project332

php7.4

Everywhere a mistake

```
    lexcodfh@artek:~/tmp [130] $ ~/.symfony/bin/symfony new test_new_project
    * Creating a new Symfony project with Composer
     [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!
!!  Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::has(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::has($id) in /home/l/lexcodfh/tmp/test_new_project/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php on line 46
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#89
!!    -error: array:4 [
!!      "type" => 64
!!      "message" => "Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::has(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::has($id)"
!!      "file" => "/home/l/lexcodfh/tmp/test_new_project/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php"
!!      "line" => 46
!!    ]
!!    #message: "Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator::has(string $id) must be compatible with Psr\Container\ContainerInterface::has($id)"
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "./vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ServiceLocator.php"
!!    #line: 46
!!  }
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd


  unable to run /home/l/lexcodfh/.local/bin/composer create-project symfony/skeleton /home/l/lexcodfh/tmp/test_new_project  --no-interaction: exit status 255
    
    lexcodfh@artek:~/tmp [1] $
```

Solution that is not applicable on hosting:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40393

Need help

Comment: Are you sure your problem is related with the issue you linked? Could you check that the mentionned extension (psr.so) is used by your php?

Comment: This library is installed on the hosting, I have no other places to check it yet 
I created a ticket on the hosting, no answer

phpinfo() =>

psr
Version  1.0.1
Released  2020-11-12
Authors  John Boehr <jbboehr@gmail.com> (lead)
PSR-3 Log Version  1.0.0
PSR-6 Cache Version  1.0.0
PSR-7 Http Message Version  1.0.0
PSR-11 Container Version  1.0.0
PSR-13 Link Version  1.0.0
PSR-14 Event Dispatcher  1.0.0
PSR-15 HTTP Handlers (Server Handler)  1.0.0
PSR-15 HTTP Handlers (Middleware)  1.0.0
PSR-16 Simple Cache Version  1.0.0
PSR-17 HTTP Factories  1.0.0
PSR-18 HTTP Client  1.0.0

Comment: Ok so it seems to be the case. I'm afraid there is no other solutions than to find a way to remove this extension from your php. Alternatively, it should works if you create your Symfony project with an other version of Symfony, maybe with the 4.4 LTS

Comment: the presence of the psr module in php versions on my hosting: 

lexcodfh@artek:~ [0] $ for i in {0..4}; do echo "Domain: php7.${i}" && php7.${i} -m -i | grep -i psr; done
Domain: php7.0 - 
Domain: php7.1 -
Domain: php7.2 -
Domain: php7.3 -
Domain: php7.4 + psr

php7.3 - no error
php7.4 error

install Symfony 4.4 LTS with php7.4 - raises a similar error 

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the `apt remove php7.4-psr php-psr` command for Debian-based distributions

Comment: To remove this for all installed PHP versions do: `apt remove php*-psr`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: i faced another error which is: 
`Declaration of Symfony\Component\Cache\CacheItem::expiresAt(?DateTimeInterface $expiration): static must be compatible with PsrExt\Cache\CacheItemInterface::expiresAt($expiration)` with spatie media library, your answer worked but i'm on php8.1